# Run my JS after views slideshow has finished loading?

Tags: 7, javascript, views

My javascript executes on window load, resize and orientation change.

```
jQuery(window).bind("load resize orientationchange",function (e) {
//do something
});
```

This worked fine until I started using the views slideshow. My code runs before the slideshow. As it measures elements on the screen it doenst work properly. If I resize the browser (so the code re-fires) then it works as expected.

How can I make my code run after views slidehow has finished loading? I also need to re-execute the code every time a slide changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue many times (especially when I used lightbox2 module), you can use the `theme_preprocess_views_view` hook or one of [Views template files](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/group/views_templates/7) and add the JS using `drupal_add_js`.

**With your code**

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(window).bind("load resize orientationchange",function (e) {
//do something
});', 'inline');
```

Thanks :)